# Use Regex from a column in Redshift

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift, literals

I have 2 tables in Redshift, one of them has a column containing Regex strings. And I want to join them like so:

```
select *
from one o
join two t
on o.value ~ t.regex
```

But this query throws an error:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: The pattern must be a valid UTF-8 literal character expression
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  The pattern must be a valid UTF-8 literal character expression
  code:      8001
  context:   
  query:     412993
  location:  cgx_impl.cpp:1911
  process:   padbmaster [pid=5211]
  -----------------------------------------------;
```

As far as I understood from searching in the docs, the right side of a regex operator `~` must be a string literal.

So this would work:

```
select *
from one o
where o.value ~ 'regex'
```

And this would fail:

```
select *
from one o
where 'regex' ~ o.value
```

Is there any way around this? Anything I missed?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the column type of `two.regex` and the collation? Can you isolate which value throws the error and tell us the value, or does it error for all values?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the built-in function `regexp_substr()` 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html

```
select *
from one o
join two t
on regexp_substr(o.value, t.regex) <> ''
```

**Edit example added of raw query**

It appears that the fields must be explicitly cast as varchars when built.

```
with fake_table as (
  SELECT 'sample value'::varchar as value, '[a-z]'::varchar as pattern
)

SELECT * 
, regexp_substr(value, pattern)
FROM
  fake_table
WHERE 
  regexp_substr(value, pattern) <>''
```

Comment: I had the same problem. I tried this solution and still get the same error: "The pattern must be a valid UTF-8 literal character expression"

Comment: It sounds like your string has some non- standard characters. Can you isolate a single row with this error, and pay the string?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE for_regex(value VARCHAR(100), pattern VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO for_regex(value, pattern) VALUES ('abc', '[a-z]');
SELECT * FROM for_regex WHERE regexp_substr(value, pattern) <> '';` . After executing the last statememnt, the error appears (yes, I have a `where` clause here, but it's the same with `join`).

Comment: Ok, the problem is that you have to explicitly cast the values as varchars.  I'm not sure why your SQL didn't work, but only after adding in `::varchar` to _both_ fields did I get it going. (updating the code block in answer)

Comment: It works when value and pattern are written explicitly in the same query as `regexp_substr` (even when the query contains subqueries or `WITH` clauses). But inserting value and pattern to a real table and then selecting them and trying to use with `regexp_substr` does not work. At least I could not make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround I am using. Maybe it's not super fast, but it works:

First create a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION is_regex_match(pattern text, s text) RETURNS BOOLEAN IMMUTABLE AS $$
  import re
  return True if re.search(pattern, s) else False
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Then use it like this (`o.value` contains a regex pattern):

```
select *
from one o
where is_regex_match(o.value, 'some string');
```